# how to connect to Android Studio emulator from host?

Tags: android, networking

I've created a virtual device via Android Studio 3.0. It connects to "AndroidWifi" and it can access the network. I have a server socket running on host machine, how can I connect the emulator to the server socket?

Answer (score 0):

In your Emulator . Go to

```
Options > Setting > Proxy
```

You can manually configure your network here.